Как исправить ошибку в QUERY, Google Sheets?
Функция:
=QUERY('Расходы/Доходы'!A4:C;"select C where C is not null and month(A)="&IFS(C5="Январь";0;C5="Февраль";1;C5="Март";2;C5="Апрель";3;C5="Май"; 4;C5="Июнь";5;C5="Июль";6;C5="Август";7;C5="Сентябрь";8;C5="Октябрь";9;C5="Ноябрь";10;C5="Декабрь";11)&" and year(A)="&C4&", sum(B) group by C";0)

Выводит ошибку "Value!":
Не удалось интерпретировать query string. Подробности: Параметр 2 в
функции QUERY:PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "," ", "" at line 1, column
61. Was expecting one of: "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... 
"skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... 
"options" ... "and" ... "or" ...

Конструкция выглядит сложно, так как я перевожу словесное название месяца из ячейки в цифровое с помощью IFS(). Моя задача — вывести категории расходов за определëнный период и потраченную сумму по каждой категории. При этом категории могут повторяться в нескольких разных ячейках.
Когда я добавляю одинарные кавычки, функция ничего не возвращает.
Всë ломается, когда я добавляю ,sum(B) group by C.
Как мне устранить данную проблему? Что я делаю не так в описании условия?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Для начала попробуйте запрос в виде строки без параметров.

У вас ошибка в самом запросе. Он должен выглядеть примерно так:
"select C, sum(B) where условия group by C"

В контексте вашей задачи:
"select C, sum(B) where C is not null and month(A)="&IFS(C5="Январь";0;C5="Февраль";1;C5="Март";2;C5="Апрель";3;C5="Май"; 4;C5="Июнь";5;C5="Июль";6;C5="Август";7;C5="Сентябрь";8;C5="Октябрь";9;C5="Ноябрь";10;C5="Декабрь";11)&" and year(A)="&C4&" group by C"


Спасибо, это сработало!
